# Draw Bar plot with percentages

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need some help in drawing bar plot with percentages. I need a plot like this:

```
bar of overall males    bar of overall females
bar of hired males      bar of hired females
x axis: Males, Females
```

I was trying something like this:

```py
y = [139437,689]  # [Overall Males, Hired Males]
z = [82693,545]   # [Overall Females, Hired Females]
x = [Males, Females]  # on x-axis

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.bar(x-0.1, y, width=0.1, color='b')
ax.bar(x, z, width=0.1, color='g')

plt.show()
```

Please help me out with code in here.

Comment: Use a twin axis

Answer (score 0):

A starting point for what you wanted to achieve could be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [139437, 82639]  # [Overall Males/Females]
z = [689, 545]   # [Hired Males/Females]
x = ['Males', 'Females']  # on x-axis

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.bar(x, y, width=0.5, color='b', label='all')
ax.bar(x, z, width=0.5, color='g', label='hired')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

But note that the difference between *Overall values* and *Hired values* is so big, that this kind of visualization might not be the best depending on your purpose.